# How do I create a specially delimited command in `xparse`

Tags: xparse

Using `\def` I can define a command as follows:

```
\def\aecmd#1 located at (#2);{---definition---}
```

I can recreate this with `xparse` as follows:

```
\NewDocumentCommand\aecmd{ u{~located~at~(}u{);}}{----definition---}
```

However, I have a situation where I want to be able to write a command with an (almost final) optional argument.  This would be a pain in the neck to do with `\def`.

I'd like a command which could be expressed as either

```
\aecmd{Manditory content}[optional content] located at (location);
```

or

```
\aecmd{Manditory content} located at (location);
```

Essentially, I would like something that works like `r` but instead of taking a single token as the delimiters can take whole strings.  Let's call this hypothetical *argument specifier* `b`

Then my desired command could be defined along these lines:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{ mob{~located~at~(}{);}{ ---something--- }
```

I'm aware I could write something like that following:

```
\NewDocumentCommand\aecmd{ mou{~located~at~(}u{);}{---definition---}
```

Further, I suppose that I could test whether or not something was passed in the 3rd argument and raise an error if there was anything there.
But this just seems clunky.  It doesn't feel right to me.

Any suggestions about how to do this better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`xparse`?  Pshaw!

EDITED to capture syntax error if optional argument is unbracketed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}

\newcommand\aecmd[1]{\def\mandatory{#1}\aecmdaux}
\def\aecmdaux#1 located at (#2);{\def\location{#2}\aecmdauxA{#1}}
\newcommand\aecmdauxA[1]{\setbox0=\hbox{%
  \if[#1[\gdef\next{\aecmdauxB#1}\else \gdef\next{syntax error}\fi}%
  \next%
}
\newcommand\aecmdauxB[1][]{%
  Optional: #1\\ Mandatory: \mandatory\\ location: \location}

\begin{document}
\aecmd{Colonel Mustard} located at (the library);

\aecmd{Colonel Mustard}[with a wrench] located at (the library);

\aecmd{Colonel Mustard} on 4th street located at (the library);
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one does not like the output of "syntax error" then in the definition of `\aecmdauxA`, the words "syntax error" can be replaced with `\aecmdauxB` and the effect will be to *ignore* the stray words in the syntax, while still producing the mandatory and location arguments.

Comment: +1 This is clever.  I like it.  But, it allows the user to do somehting like `\aecmd{Colonel Mustard} on 4th street located at (the library);` and might not notice that this is creating spurious output.

Comment: @A.Ellett I designed it based on your two specified input syntax variations provided in the question.  What you just gave in the above comment does not fit that form...how should such a thing be digested?  Are you implying that optional content should not be specified in brackets?

Comment: What I'm saying is if something is passed as a 2nd argument that's not in square brackets, then the syntax should be wrong.  Anyhow, I do like your solution.  It just doesn't catch an input error if the 2nd argument isn't in square brackets.

Comment: @A.Ellett So, to be clear, the 2nd argument should be in brackets, but if it is not, you would like an error generated?  Or do you want all the non bracketed content to be taken as the optional argument?  I can do that pretty easy.

Comment: I wouldn't like using nonbracketed content as the optional argument.  But, if you've got more tricks that I'm unaware of about generating an error: do by all means share.

Comment: @A.Ellett Pulled out of my sleeve...or, wherever.

Answer (score 5):

With `xparse`, but I find such syntax a very bad idea, notwithstanding Ti*k*Z using it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\aecmd}{mou{located~at~(}u{);}}
 {
  \tl_if_blank:nF { #3 } { \ERROR }
  \noindent
  #1~(mandatory)\\
  \IfValueT{#2}{#2~(optional)\\}
  #4~(final)
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\aecmd{Mandatory content}[optional content] located at (location);

\aecmd{Mandatory content} located at (location);

\aecmd{Colonel Mustard} on 4th street located at (the library);

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the third call raises an error.

Comment: Actually, `TikZ` is the reason for me using this sort of syntax.  So you're solution is basically the same as my *wonky* approach.  Though I hadn't thought of testing for non-blank.

Comment: @A.Ellett `xparse` is not the best for this. See how Ti*k*Z does, instead.